# Print out each content in a separate page use QTextdocument in Qt C++

Tags: qt, c++11

I am a newbie in Qt c++.
I use QTextdocment to print PDF format.
My QTextdocment (doc) is quite long, it consists of separate content. So how can I print out each content in a separate page.

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
    printer.setOutputFileName(ui->lE_Save->text()+ ".pdf");
    doc.setDocumentMargin(0);
    doc.setTextWidth(0.5);
    doc.print(&printer);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Ps: I use QTextCursor for insert text data. I not good about html or css

Comment: In what way does this not work as expected?

Comment: @hoangtruong I honestly do not quite understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to all of you.
I got the solution to export the contents page by page in PDF format.
My code something like that:

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    QPageSize pageSize(QPageSize::A4);
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&printer);
    for...
    {
    QTextDocument doc;
            QTextCursor cursor(&doc);

    ...do something for QTextDocument ...

     doc.drawContents(&painter);
            if(page!=monthCount-1)
                printer.newPage();
    }
    painter.end();
```